# linking 2 mysql tables thanks to a third liaison table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

1. img : id, name
2. fig : id, x, y, z
3. link : id, imgid, figid

I use the 'link' table to connect certain img ids to certain fig ids (I hope it's clear)

Question: I am struggling to find the correct SQL query to find "all the fig that are connected to a specific img id"

I am working with php / mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign to yourID the value you nedd eg: 33

```
 select fig.* 
 from fig
 inner join link  on link.figid = fid.id
 inner join img on link.imgid = yourID
```

in your case

```
 select fig.* 
 from fig
 inner join link  on link.figid = fid.id
 inner join img on link.imgid = 33
```